# authentication in singalR selfhost server- and web client in SSL

Tags: signalr, signalr.client

I have a singalR self host server that is hosting my singalR in a console application on https

I am using this packages to self host:

- Install-Package Microsoft.Owin.Hosting -pre
  Install-Package Microsoft.Owin.Host.HttpListener -pre
  Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Owin

i have a web client which is backed by WebApi, I can connect to my selfhosted singalR from my webclient and send messages however I would now like to add authentication to this, which means only logged in users can send messages to my selfhosted singalR server.
I used [Authorize] attribute before my method

```
[Authorize]
public void Test(string test)
{
    Console.WriteLine(test);   
}
```

I have my web client authentication done via forms authentication however after logging in sucessfully in my webclient, when i do call singalR method, i recieve javascript error

Uncaught Value cannot be null. Parameter name: user

It tells that my method is protected but somehow my user is not passed to my self hosted singalR server, What is missing here?

Answer (score 1):

Support for this was introduced with SignalR 1.0, you can read a little about that on [David Fowlers blog](http://weblogs.asp.net/davidfowler/archive/2012/11/11/microsoft-asp-net-signalr.aspx). The problem is, with it being so new it's a little sparsely documented.

I'm not exactly sure what's going on in your application at the moment but you can find a similar question already on Stack Overflow which might help you get on the right track: [Integrating SignalR with existing Authorization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14343531/integrating-signalr-with-existing-authorization)

Basically, you can create a SignalR Attribute that implements IAuthorizeHubConnection and IAuthorizeHubMethodInvocation, then decorate your Hubs/Methods that you want authorized.

```
public class HubAuthorizeAttribute : Attribute, IAuthorizeHubConnection, IAuthorizeHubMethodInvocation {

    public virtual bool AuthorizeHubConnection(HubDescriptor hubDescriptor, Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.IRequest request) {

        IAuthorizationProvider authorizationProvider = DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<IAuthorizationProvider>();

        return authorizationProvider.IsAuthorizedController(hubDescriptor.Name);
    }    

    public virtual bool AuthorizeHubMethodInvocation(IHubIncomingInvokerContext hubIncomingInvokerContext) {

        IAuthorizationProvider authorizationProvider = DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<IAuthorizationProvider>();

        return authorizationProvider.IsAuthorizedAction(hubIncomingInvokerContext.MethodDescriptor.Hub.Name, hubIncomingInvokerContext.MethodDescriptor.Name);
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you could add the HubAuthorizeAttribute as a HubPipeline Module to Globally require Authorization.

```
var globalAuthorizer = new HubAuthorizeAttribute ();
GlobalHost.HubPipeline.AddModule(new AuthorizeModule(globalAuthorizer, globalAuthorizer));
```

Answer (score 0):

I've asked a similar question a few times over the last days in the SignalR JabbR chat and haven't got any answer.
When I was about to post my question here I found your question and [this other one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15843849/implementing-authorization-in-a-self-hosted-signalr-server-accessed-from-web). Unfortunately, from the answer given there a couple of weeks ago, it seems like SignalR itself provides no Authentication support, so that's a huge problem for many selfhosted applications (we were intending to use Integrated Windows Authentication with SignalR...)